# Bit unstuffing without delimiter.Is it possible?

Tags: networking

I have to unstuff the sequence of bit: 011111100001111011111011111011001111110.
But the delimiter is not provided in the question.How can I do bit unstuffing?

Comment: "delimiter", do you have *any* information about where the non-information bits are in this stream? Or any information about how big the output should be, or what it may denote? In short, do you have any other information about this bit-stream, *other* than the bit-stream?

Comment: No, nothing is provided except for the bit-stream.I think flag/delimiter should be provided.

Comment: Then as far as I can tell, this is a defunct question, impossible to answer. Not enough information.